# Настройка xDebug Docker-compose в PhpStorm (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: ubuntu, phpstorm, docker, xdebug

Ответ оказался прост: здесь стоит использовать не слушателя, а нажимать кнопку жучка. Вопрос оставлю может кому пригодиться

Второй день не могу разобраться в причине не работающего дебагера. Шторм сигнал видит, но не обрабатывает. Думал мапинг не правильно настроен, но, вроде верно. Кратко о проекте: в папке docker лежат файлы докера, в вложенных папках (docker/www/html) - проект сайта.
Подскажите что не так или хотя бы в какую сторону копать, а то уже кучу всего перелопатил. Спасибо!

Настройки xdebug-settings.ini:

```
xdebug.remote_enable=On
xdebug.remote_host=192.168.0.16
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.idekey="PHPSTORM"
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
xdebug.remote_log=/usr/share/nginx/html/tmp/xdebug.log
```

Настройки PHPSTORM (по названию серверов видно что там указано в строке Host):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При включенном дебагере выдает следующее:

> Cannot accept external Xdebug connection: Cannot evaluate expression
>   'isset($_SERVER['PHP_IDE_CONFIG'])'

При валидации серверов следующее
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Причина может быть в том, что xdebug не видит phpstorm и 192.168.0.16 может быть недоступен из контейнера. В своей конфигурации xdebug я убрал xdebug.remote_host и добавил xdebug.remote_connect_back=1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ оказался прост: здесь стоит использовать не слушателя, а нажимать кнопку жучка. Вопрос оставлю может кому пригодиться. Всем спасибо за отклики

Answer (score 0):

Возможно не был открыт порт. Надо открыть порт на компе для приёма информации от xDebug.

```
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 9000 -j ACCEPT
```